# Multiple (3) RF transmitters to a single receiver?

Tags: arduino-uno, rf

How can I have three remote transmitters send distinct signals to a single receiver?

My project requires 3 remote controls, each with 2 inputs.

I need to distinctly identify these 6 signals from the 3 remotes onto one arduino board.

Is this possible to do with one receiver?

Would I be able to pair one remote to one receiver (so 3 receivers), or will there be noise / interference?

What is the simplest and/or cheapest solution to this?

FYI I am going to be using a 315 Mhz remote / receiver (remote control has 4 inputs). I am waiting for them to come in the mail but I want to start thinking about how I will build this.

Comment: What transmitters?

Comment: Please provide exact reference to these transmitters/receivers. Also, what Arduino library do you use to interface with these devices?

Comment: Why all of the down votes? What dose this question lack? Despite the absence of the exact library and device, this concept of this question is clear I think

Answer (score 3):

These transmitter all transmit on the same frequency so if you have multiple receivers they will all get the same signal.

The only way I can see you can do this is make some type of protocol where you send data with a station ID and only the receiver with the station ID matching the message will act on it.

EDIT:

Sorry have to get used to the double-enter making a send.

@JamesWierzba your 'remotes' will need to be more than just a push button to send a HIGH or LOW signal via the transmitter.

Your 'remotes' will need to each have a unique ID, we usually use DIP switches for this. A small microcontroller will need to read these DIP switch and compose the message to be send to the receiver.

A simple message like "ID_BUTTON_PRESS" where ID is the decimal or hex equivalent of the DIP switches.

On reception of the message the microcontroller receiving the message will know which remote it comes from by looking at the ID part of the message.

Comment: So each transmitter  will have a unique ID? In the message?

Comment: Well, without code they don't, you would have to make your own code to do so.

Comment: Oups pressed sent too fast.

You could use the VirtualWire library -> https://www.pjrc.com/teensy/td_libs_VirtualWire.html

Comment: Let's give a simple example. You program each receiver with an ID (1, 2 or 3). At the start of every transmission you put the ID of the device you'd like to send to. For example: 2,test. All your receivers get this message, but only the receiver with ID equals 2 will use it. The rest will discard the message.

Comment: @Len I'm broadcasting from 3 tramistters, not trying to receive on 3 different receivers (although I can if necassary). The basic problem is this: I have 3 remotes ( 3 people each hold a remote). I need to know which person pressed it. IS that more clear?

Comment: Yes, but same principle applies. Let each transmitter send their ID as well and you know which transmitter was used.

Comment: @JamesWierzba your 'remotes' will need to be more than just a push button to send a HIGH or LOW signal via the transmitter.